# under the hood execution of if condition in PHP

Tags: php, if-statement, logical-operators, php-7.1

Following block of code throws an exception that variable `$booking` is undefined. can someone explain why?

```
if(
     trim($request->id)!='' 
     && $booking = Booking::find($request->id) 
     && $booking->user_id == auth()->user()->id // undefined variable $booking
       ) {
          return response()->json($booking);
    }
    else {
          return response()->json(['message' => 'not found'],404);
    }
```

However this works without any issue

```
if(
    trim($request->id)!='' 
    && $booking = Booking::find($request->id)
    ) {
      if($booking->user_id == auth()->user()->id)
                    return response()->json($booking);
}
return response()->json(['message' => 'not found'],404);
```

Comment: Take a look at the [operator precedence](http://php.net/manual/fa/language.operators.precedence.php). You need parentheses around `$booking = Booking::find($request->id)`, because assignments have a low precedence.

Comment: @jh1711 is correct. https://3v4l.org/udBtn Also you should really use the strict comparison `!== ''` as an empty string is considered "false-y" by PHP and is loosely equivalent to a number of other false-y things of different types.

Answer (score -5):

The two fragments of code you gave, the one that is throwing an exception, and the one that is working, are not equivalent. The first one is missing the boolean expression `$booking->user_id != null`. Probalby, you should code:

```
if(
     trim($request->id)!='' 
     && $booking = Booking::find($request->id) 
     && $booking->user_id != null               // added stuff here
     && $booking->user_id == auth()->user()->id // $booking no more undefined 
       ) {
          return response()->json($booking);
    }
    else {
          return response()->json(['message' => 'not found'],404);
    }
```

Comment: This will throw the same error. You try to access $booking->user_id before the assignment.

Comment: it also works without $booking->user_id != null. anyway i updated the question